# RapidMiner - process data table rows as documents

Tags: mysql, rapidminer

I need help about the following question: i would process each row from a data table (Example set structure (`label[datatype]): mid[int], body[text]`), obtained by Read Database, as a document. In this way i can apply some filters to each document (stop-words, filters, and so on). Can anyone help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.015">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Server Connection" width="90" x="112" y="120">
        <parameter key="connection" value="Server"/>
        <parameter key="query" value="SELECT `mid`, `body` FROM `message` WHERE `mid` &lt; 10 ORDER BY `mid`"/>
        <enumeration key="parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="loop_data_sets" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Loop Data Sets" width="90" x="111" y="210">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="text:extract_document" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" name="Extract Document (2)">
            <parameter key="attribute_name" value="body"/>
            <parameter key="example_index" value="1"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:transform_cases" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" name="Transform Cases (2)"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" name="Tokenize (2)"/>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_stopwords_dictionary" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" name="Filter Stopwords (2)">
            <parameter key="file" value="C:\User\stopwords.txt"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_by_length" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" name="Filter Tokens (2)">
            <parameter key="min_chars" value="2"/>
          </operator>
          <connect from_port="example set" to_op="Extract Document (2)" to_port="example set"/>
          <connect from_op="Extract Document (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Transform Cases (2)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Transform Cases (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize (2)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Tokenize (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Stopwords (2)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Stopwords (2)" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Tokens (2)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Filter Tokens (2)" from_port="document" to_port="output 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_example set" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_performance" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_output 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Server Connection" from_port="output" to_op="Loop Data Sets" to_port="example set 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Loop Data Sets" from_port="output 1" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: i've obtained in output only a document and not a set of documents, one for each row

Comment: Posting "SOLVED" and editing your question to add the solution is not how StackOverflow works. If you found a solution, you should write an answer and provide that solution in that answer. (Answering your own question is [encouraged here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can even accept it as the correct answer; although you won't gain any reputation for doing so, it lets others know your question has been answered, and shares that information more readily with future readers that may have the same problem. Thanks. (I'll leave for a short time before rolling back your edit.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, i'm only interested in answers and in knowledge sharing

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <process version="5.3.015">
      <context>
        <input/>
        <output/>
        <macros/>
      </context>
      <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" name="Process">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Server Connection" width="90" x="45" y="75">
            <parameter key="connection" value="Server"/>
            <parameter key="query" value="SELECT `mid`, `body` FROM `message` WHERE `mid` &lt; 10 ORDER BY `mid`"/>
            <enumeration key="parameters"/>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="text:process_document_from_data" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Process Documents from Data (2)" width="90" x="45" y="165">
            <parameter key="create_word_vector" value="false"/>
            <parameter key="add_meta_information" value="false"/>
            <parameter key="keep_text" value="true"/>
            <list key="specify_weights"/>
            <process expanded="true">
              <operator activated="true" class="web:extract_html_text_content" compatibility="5.3.001" expanded="true" height="60" name="Extract Content" width="90" x="45" y="30">
                <parameter key="minimum_text_block_length" value="3"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="text:transform_cases" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Transform Cases" width="90" x="45" y="120"/>
              <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Tokenize (3)" width="90" x="45" y="210"/>
              <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_stopwords_dictionary" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="76" name="Filter Stopwords (3)" width="90" x="45" y="300">
                <parameter key="file" value="C:\User\stopwords.txt"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="text:filter_by_length" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Filter Tokens (3)" width="90" x="45" y="390">
                <parameter key="min_chars" value="3"/>
              </operator>
              <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Delete links" width="90" x="45" y="480">
                <parameter key="mode" value="regular expression"/>
                <parameter key="expression" value="(http[s]?://[a-z_\.A-Z0-9\-]*)"/>
              </operator>
              <connect from_port="document" to_op="Extract Content" to_port="document"/>
              <connect from_op="Extract Content" from_port="document" to_op="Transform Cases" to_port="document"/>
              <connect from_op="Transform Cases" from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize (3)" to_port="document"/>
              <connect from_op="Tokenize (3)" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Stopwords (3)" to_port="document"/>
              <connect from_op="Filter Stopwords (3)" from_port="document" to_op="Filter Tokens (3)" to_port="document"/>
              <connect from_op="Filter Tokens (3)" from_port="document" to_op="Delete links" to_port="document"/>
              <connect from_op="Delete links" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
              <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
              <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
            </process>
          </operator>
          <operator activated="true" class="generate_id" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="76" name="Generate ID" width="90" x="179" y="165"/>
          <connect from_op="Server Connection" from_port="output" to_op="Process Documents from Data (2)" to_port="example set"/>
          <connect from_op="Process Documents from Data (2)" from_port="example set" to_op="Generate ID" to_port="example set input"/>
          <connect from_op="Generate ID" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
    </process>
```